# Underline part of a link on hover of whole link

Tags: css

I have a link - notifications - with a red disc next to it. I would like hover on the disc OR text to result in the text only being underlined (I also would like clicking anywhere in link to go to the same link).

[image]

I can find nothing in Google about this specific issue.

Everything I try makes the 1 get an underline as well as the notifications text:

HTML

```
<div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-5" id="nav">
    <div class="userbox">
        <a href="#"><span class="numbercir">1</span> Notifications</a> | 
        <a href="~/Signin">Signin</a> | <a href="~/Signup">Signup</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.numbercir {
    border-radius: 3px;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    padding: 2px 3px;   
    background: #f00;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;  
    font: 12px Arial, sans-serif;
}
/* This doesn't work - ie doesn't stop the 1 getting an underline */
a .numbercircle:hover {
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

How can I do this? Thx. (HTML 5 / CSS3 are fine as long as the technique has wide browser support).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put the part you want to be underlined in a span.

This has also the effect, that you will online get the underline, when you go over that specific span.

```css
a .ca:hover {
 text-decoration:underline;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" style="text-decoration:none">ABC<span class="ca">CD</span></a>
```

And in case you want to underline only a certain part not only when you hover over that part, just change css to this:

```css
a:hover .ca {
 text-decoration:underline;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" style="text-decoration:none">ABC<span class="ca">CD</span></a>
```

I hope I got you right this time :-)

Comment: 'online' is that a typo? to confirm I want hover on the whole thing - to underline the text only.

Comment: @Daidon, I still think it does not meet OP's requirement... 'CD' should be underlined, when I hover anywhere on the whole word

Comment: simply change CSS to a:hover .ca {...} then, I will make an example

Answer (score 2):

You could make the notification count a pseudo element positioned absolutely, then add the count as an attribute. That way your html would stay simple & clean. So the html would look like this:

```
<a href="#" class="numbercircle" data-number="12">Notifications</a>
```

Functional example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/p0593yz9/1/

Comment: Just a matter of preference. The other mentioned solutions require you to wrap whatever link text you want to underline in a span element.

Comment: Just a note - this does not work in IE 11 (but does work in Edge)

Comment: Good catch, I've updated the solution to be compatible back to IE8

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
a .highlight:hover {
 text-decoration:underline;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" style="text-decoration:none">Notif<span class="highlight">ications | Loc</span>ations</a>
```